# How to read lines in R starting with certain string

Tags: r

Suppose I have a text file such as below. My question is how to read the lines starting with `SN` in R. The whole file has over 10k rows but I just wanted the lines starting with `SN`.

```
# This file was produced by samtools stats (1.10+htslib-1.10.2) and can be plotted using plot-bamstats
# CHK, CRC32 of reads which passed filtering followed by addition (32bit overflow)
CHK     c643fc89        1179dda6        e11a337d
# Summary Numbers. Use `grep ^SN | cut -f 2-` to extract this part.
SN      raw total sequences:    1784681
SN      filtered sequences:     0
SN      sequences:      1784681
SN      is sorted:      1
SN      1st fragments:  894414
# First Fragment Qualities. Use `grep ^FFQ | cut -f 2-` to extract this part.
# Columns correspond to qualities and rows to cycles. First column is the cycle number.
FFQ     1       0       0       143     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       12403   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       13187   0       0       3879    42036   14537   37413   9464    761352  0       0       0       0       0       0
FFQ     2       0       0       4       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       11751   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       11151   0       0       5740    40065   18407   34914   14779   757603  0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `readLines()` and then `grep` the SN's. Reads in the whole thing first, though.

```
rl <- readLines('test.txt')
rl[grep('^SN.*', rl)]
# [1] "SN      raw total sequences:    1784681" "SN      filtered sequences:     0"      
# [3] "SN      sequences:      1784681"         "SN      is sorted:      1"              
# [5] "SN      1st fragments:  894414"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid reading in everything at once you might try `awk`:

```r
infile <- tempfile()

lines <- "# This file was produced by samtools stats (1.10+htslib-1.10.2) and can be plotted using plot-bamstats
# CHK, CRC32 of reads which passed filtering followed by addition (32bit overflow)
CHK     c643fc89        1179dda6        e11a337d
# Summary Numbers. Use `grep ^SN | cut -f 2-` to extract this part.
SN      raw total sequences:    1784681
SN      filtered sequences:     0
SN      sequences:      1784681
SN      is sorted:      1
SN      1st fragments:  894414
# First Fragment Qualities. Use `grep ^FFQ | cut -f 2-` to extract this part.
# Columns correspond to qualities and rows to cycles. First column is the cycle number.
FFQ     1       0       0       143     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       12403   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       13187   0       0       3879    42036   14537   37413   9464    761352  0       0       0       0       0       0
FFQ     2       0       0       4       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       11751   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       11151   0       0       5740    40065   18407   34914   14779   757603  0       0       0       0       0       0"

writeLines(lines, infile)

awk_cmd <- sprintf("awk '$1 ~ /^SN/' %s", infile)

readLines(pipe(awk_cmd))
#> [1] "SN      raw total sequences:    1784681"
#> [2] "SN      filtered sequences:     0"      
#> [3] "SN      sequences:      1784681"        
#> [4] "SN      is sorted:      1"              
#> [5] "SN      1st fragments:  894414"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Read in the whole file with `readLines()` function. This will give you a character vector of length equal to the number of lines in your file. You can then use `grepl()` to find vector elements ("rows") that start with `SN`.

```
xy <- "# This file was produced by samtools stats (1.10+htslib-1.10.2) and can be plotted using plot-bamstats
# CHK, CRC32 of reads which passed filtering followed by addition (32bit overflow)
CHK     c643fc89        1179dda6        e11a337d
# Summary Numbers. Use `grep ^SN | cut -f 2-` to extract this part.
SN      raw total sequences:    1784681
SN      filtered sequences:     0
SN      sequences:      1784681
SN      is sorted:      1
SN      1st fragments:  894414
# First Fragment Qualities. Use `grep ^FFQ | cut -f 2-` to extract this part.
# Columns correspond to qualities and rows to cycles. First column is the cycle number.
FFQ     1       0       0       143     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       12403   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       13187   0       0       3879    42036   14537   37413   9464    761352  0       0       0       0       0       0
FFQ     2       0       0       4       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       11751   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       11151   0       0       5740    40065   18407   34914   14779   757603  0       0       0       0       0       0"

tf <- tempfile("read_sn")
cat(xy, file = tf)

sn <- readLines(con = tf)
sn[grepl("^SN", sn)]

[1] "SN      raw total sequences:    1784681"
[2] "SN      filtered sequences:     0"      
[3] "SN      sequences:      1784681"        
[4] "SN      is sorted:      1"              
[5] "SN      1st fragments:  894414" 

unlink(x = tf)
```